# Determine on which route from a list of routes an express middleware was called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following case:

There is a list of routes in the form

```
var lst = ["route1/:foo", "route2/:bar", "route3/:bar/route4/:baz", ..] // this list has like 200 entries
```

I have the following code

```
app.use(lst, function (req, res) {
  // here I want to know which route the middleware was invoked on
  // req.route.path doesn't work unless I use app.METHOD()
  // req.originalUrl would give me route1/200, instead of route1/:foo
})
```

What I tried so far:

1. Using the router stack as in `app._router.stack`, my routes aren't even registered there - I don't see `route1/:foo`, `route2/:bar` and `route3/:bar/route4/:baz`
2. Hook into the express router:

```
var Route = express.Route;

let defaultImplementation = Route.prototype.dispatch;

function foo(req, res) {
  console.log('Called route ', req.route.path); // still doesn't trigger on the routes in lst, only parent routes
}

Route.prototype.dispatch = function handle(req, res, next) {
  foo(req, res); // req.route is available here
  defaultImplementation.call(this, req, res, next);
};
```

By the way, I'm passing those routes and using them along with `http-proxy-middleware` https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware, so if you have any clues on how do achieve that with that library as well, I'd be very grateful as I couldn't find out.

Comment: Why doesn't a requested route to `route1/200` directly correspond to `route1/:foo` since there can by one-and-only-one endpoint with that signature. The same holds true for every endpoint in the `lst` array.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If I request route1/200, I want to log route1/:foo, in other words, the route definition that was matched. Just like req.route.path.

Comment: As in this conditional pseudo:  if(req === 'route1/200') { then route configuration === `route1/:foo` } <-- There can be no other case. You already have a look up table in the `lst` array, all you have to do is isolate which array entry matches the pattern of the req and you have your answer.